# Does system user access token's data expiry get set to never for all end user in production?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, instagram-graph-api

According to the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/facebook-login-for-business#system-user-access-token-flow-testing), if the app is in Dev mode then to generate a system user access token, the tester has to be the admin of client business, partner business, and app.

Is this restriction also applicable when the app is in production mode? Or will the system user access token be generated for every user who connects their page to our app?

It is not very clear in the documentation. I would truly appreciate it if anyone could clarify.

NB. This is for Facebook login for business (v17.0)